# What is causing a blue colour when sodium bicarbonate, vinegar and aluminium are reacted together?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, home-experiment, identification

My 10 year old has been experimenting in my kitchen!
The other day he wanted to know why when he reacted bicarb soda and boiling vinegar in a container with some aluminium foil, the solution turned blue.
I have no idea!
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Search "home chemistry for kids". This looks a good one  https://mommypoppins.com/kids/50-easy-science-experiments-for-kids-fun-educational-activities-using-household-stuff

Comment: Would be better to know which kind of vinegar. Wine apple or just acetic acid and caramel might made a difference. Or there was some cupper around

Comment: Aluminum foil could contain copper as an impurity.  This "shouldn't" react with the nonoxidizing acid but could be oxidized by air.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. It was standard kitchen white vinegar that he used. Cheers.

Comment: Hi all. Even though I saw the blue result at the time, I thought I'd better let you know that I tried replicating the experiment exactly the way he said he did it just now, same porcelain mug, same ingredients and didn't get any blue - very mysterious! He promises there's no food colouring tricks in there (and the blue did seem too light to be a drop of food colouring).